# How to unistall 13.10 on a dual boot XP machine

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, 13.10, uninstall, windows-xp

I am new to Linux in general. As I am sure is the case with many of the new converts, I have an old XP machine that is getting slow and about to be unsupported so I decided to test the waters. I installed 13.10 along side XP only to find that my graphics chip doesn't support the Unity interface upgrade in 13.10 (no launcher, icons, etc). I did download 12.04 after the fact and confirmed that its interface does work (ran it from a flash drive). As I see it, I have 2 options: try to downgrade (which is officially unsupported) or remove 13.10 and install 12.04 fresh.

I looked up the process on removing 13.10, which is pretty simple (wipe out the partitions containing Ubunutu), but it also takes GRUB with it. I downloaded and tried to run EasyBCD to restore the master boot record, but it does not support XP Home. I don't have the original XP disc to repair it via that avenue either. Do I have any other options here that I don't know about? Thanks!

Comment: Won't the 12.04 LTS live DVD suggest to remove the entire 13.04 installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRUB shouldn't be necessary for Windows XP to run so I'm pretty confident you can do that, but you should always back-up your data.

Since the root cause is that you graphics chip isn't sufficient for Unity, you can skip the entire downgrade process by installing a different desktop environment.

To do so, you can boot into linux and open a terminal (if you are unable to open a terminal due to the graphics incompatibility, press `ctrl + alt + F1` to start a new session without X running and log-in)

You can install a new desktop environment with `apt-get`. [This article](http://www.maketecheasier.com/use-different-desktop-environments-in-ubuntu/) gives a few examples and screenshots. Perhaps a lightweight DE like XFCE would be a good choice, but just see what you like.

When you log in again, you can select your newly chosen desktop environment.

Comment: Thank you, this got me up and running! I am very new to Linux and did not realize that you could have multiple DEs, this has totally sold me on Linux. Thanks for taking the time to help out a n00b instead of just marking this as a duplicate. I searched for hours before asking the question here, but sometimes you are too new to even know what you are searching for.

Comment: It's no problem. I guess technically the question is a duplicate, but a rollback wasn't necessarily the solution to the problem. Besides, the more duplicates, the easier it is to find the answer :)